# Draw ImageView on Android Canvas (with specific position)?

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-canvas

I have a canvas and I can see it and everything works fine.

Now I want to draw an `ImageView` on the canvas,
and set the `ImageView` to specific position with X and Y values.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

One cannot draw another control inside the canvas. The canvas is just like a real world canvas an artist uses, you can only draw stuff in it. I cannot say I need a real chocolate on the diagram, but you can draw a chocolate if you want. It's as simple as that.

If you want to draw a image at a specific position use this code in your `onDraw` method:

```
super.onDraw(canvas);
p=new Paint();
Bitmap b=BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.icon);
p.setColor(Color.RED);
canvas.drawBitmap(b, 0, 0, p);
```

Comment: It's a bad answer. I don't understand you, How to use this code? I need to draw image with specific coordinates.

Comment: Thank you @DynoCris. This answer is pretty old and most of the variants of this `drawBitmap` function are now deprecated. However, the one in the above does let you draw with a specific x and y co-ordinates. Please check the syntax for more details(https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas#drawBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint)